# Wildcard search in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table called SearchData which has 'title' and 'description' columns.

Table name: SearchData

Columns: ID  TITLE  URL  DESCRIPTION

User searches for a string like for example "technical assistance".

The query should return all rows by searching titles and descriptions with the words 'technical' and 'assistance'.

Like for example if the description has text 'we provide technical and professional assistance', that row should be selected.

Can you suggest the best way to do this in Entity framework? I am unable to do wildcard search

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for records that contains all the words you can just concatenate Where clause (If you need or is a little bit Tricky).

```
var myQuery = context.SearchData;
foreach (string word in words)
    myQuery = myQuery.Where(s => s.URL.Contains(word) || s.DESCRIPTION.Contains(word));

var results = myQuery.ToList();
```

**EDIT**

If you need to search for *all words in URL* **OR** *all words in DESCRIPTION* you can use this

```
var myQuery1 = context.SearchData;
foreach (string word in words)
    myQuery1 = myQuery1.Where(s => s.URL.Contains(word));

var myQuery2 = context.SearchData;
foreach (string word in words)
    myQuery2 = myQuery2.Where(s => s.DESCRIPTION.Contains(word));

var results = myQuery1.Union(myQuery2).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, I did exactly the same, it is returning the results with only 'technical' and only 'assistance' as well.. I am looking to get the results with both the words in title and description. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean that _all the words should be in URL_ **OR** _all the words should be in DESCRIPTION_? Because in this case you need to concatenate 2 different where clause with an **OR** in the "middle".

Comment: If you need an **OR** you can probably also use `Union`

Comment: yes, if all the words are in TITLE or if all the words are in DESCRIPTION, then that row should be selected

Comment: union in the above query will search for each word in both 'title' and 'description', so that wont work, right? I am looking for search for all words in TITLE or search for all words in DESCRIPTION

Comment: I updated the answer. Check it and tell me if it works please (it should but I did not try it so I'm curious).